# Assigning IP Address ranges - Protocol, Best Practices

Tags: switch, ip-address, networking

I am looking for standard procedures when assigning a range for static ip addresses. Which are the most commonly used approaches and why. I am trying to look on the internet and this forum, however all the answers I find to this question are vague.

Let's say I have a x.x.x.1 /24 (1-254) , multiple switches 2-4, multiple servers 8-16 and multiple idracs 8-16.

Should I start from the bottom and use the first ip-addresses for the switches? which is the best logic?

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about "best practices" lead to multiple opinions which are off-topic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no one-size-fits-all approach to this, as needs vary widely.  Networks are often heavy on switches and routers, servers, or laptops, but very rarely all of these.

For a typical self-contained /24, I'd suggest something like the following, based on a layout I made for a client with many small offices and which they used for about 20 years now.

- .1 to .7 routers
- .8 to .15 switches (from bottom) / access points (from top)
- .16 to .31 specials
- .32 to .47 servers (application from bottom, DNS etc from top)
- .48 to .63 printers
- .64 to .239 DHCP laptops/workstations
- .240 to .254 static laptops/workstations

Servers are allocated in pairs, so there's space for a backup machine if required.  Ie file servers might be 32, 34 ..., name servers might be 46, 44 ...  Specials are for things which you have few of, perhaps scanners, CCTV, audio; perhaps in your case you'd assign those addresses for your iDRACs.

For more unusual networks, you need to design your own.